# MVC3 Application Inside Webforms Application Routing is throwing a HttpContext.SetSessionStateBehavior Error in IIS7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5, webforms

I'm running a mixed MVC Application inside a sub folder of a web forms application.

Everything worked great in VS 2010 debug (Cassini) but when I deployed to IIS7.5

I got the following error:

```
'HttpContext.SetSessionStateBehavior' can only be invoked before
  'HttpApplication.AcquireRequestState' event is raised.
```

It errors on the last line (`httpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current);`) in the `default.aspx` file of the MVC application sub folder.

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string pathToRewriteTo = Request.Path.ToLowerInvariant().Replace("default.aspx", "Home/Index");

    HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(pathToRewriteTo, false);

    IHttpHandler httpHandler = new MvcHttpHandler();

    httpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current);
}
```

However if I manually navigate to Home/Index from the MVC root folder I can see my application fine from there.

I've looked up the error being thrown and I only find answers dealing with server transfers and not MVC routes.

I have also already checked my `IIS7.5` configuration for the route handling module, Application pool running in integrated mode, etc.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

We faced a similar issue. There are changes to MVCHttpHandler in MVC2 and above.

You need to change it to use `httpContext.Server.TransferRequest`.

Try the below snippet:

```
var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
httpContext.Server.TransferRequest(Url, true); // change to false to pass query string parameters if you have already processed them
```